# Is there an easy Regex expression to capture a reference code that continuously changes?

Tags: regex, rubular

Let's say I have a string:

```
Success: Feed File Uploaded.  Use the reference code afc3d6e84df84f51944a06cccee8f59a to track these records in the logs.
```

What I need to capture is the reference code only, the **afc3d6e84df84f51944a06cccee8f59a**. It's 32 characters in this example but I'm not sure if it will always be 32. It looks like some kind of computation or hash that would probably typically have a set number of characters but the reference code will always be different. I've looked up some examples to see if there's a way to capture a string that contains an exact specific number of characters you know it to have but only saw a few things like

.{32}^ that didn't pertain to my example. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a hash of some sort, and you can match it with the following regular expression:

```
/([0-9a-f]{32}){1,2}/
```

That will only match hash strings like this one, since this will match a hexadecimal string of either 32 or 64 characters long. [Here's a demo](http://regex101.com/r/sE9wN0) that demonstrates this.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte No it's not. It makes the group match 1 or 2 times, ensuring it would match either 32 characters, or 64 characters if the string is 64 characters long.